The difference Between Python's += and + Operators with Lists
I'm observing a discrepancy in Python's behavior when using the += and + operators with lists. Consider the following code snippets:
x = [1, 2]
y = x
x += [3]
y += [4]
print(x is y)  # Output is True

In this case, the output is True, indicating that x and y reference the same object in memory. However, when I slightly modify the code:
x = [1, 2]
y = x
x += [3]
y = y + [4]
print(x is y)  # Output is False

The output is False, suggesting that x and y now reference different objects. While += is often considered syntactic sugar for list concatenation, this behavior contradicts that understanding.
Could someone clarify the difference in behavior between += and + when used with lists? I'm interested in understanding the underlying mechanisms.
edit:
from dis import dis

def suger(list):
    list += [3]
    return list

def no_suger(list):
    list = list + [3]
    return list

dis(suger) # returns
"""
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_FAST                0 (list)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              6 BUILD_LIST               1
              8 BINARY_OP               13 (+=)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (list)

  4          14 LOAD_FAST                0 (list)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
"""

dis(no_suger) # returns
"""
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 LOAD_FAST                0 (list)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              6 BUILD_LIST               1
              8 BINARY_OP                0 (+)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (list)

  4          14 LOAD_FAST                0 (list)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
"""

When using dis module I found a difference in line 8:
Sugar:      8 BINARY_OP  13 (+=)
No Sugar:   8 BINARY_OP   0 (+)


BINARY_OP 13 (+=): This instruction performs in-place addition. It modifies the object in place and assigns the result back to the variable. When used with lists, it modifies the original list by appending the right-hand side to it.

BINARY_OP 0 (+): This instruction performs regular addition. It does not modify the original object, but instead creates a new object that is the result of the addition. When used with lists, it concatenates the two lists together and returns a new list without modifying the original lists.



list1 += list2 is equivalent to list1.extend(list2), not list1 = list1 + list2. It doesn't create a new list.

More generally, x += y is intended to be implemented with x = x.__iadd__(y), only falling back to x = x.__add__(y) when x.iaddis not defined. This provides the *opportunity* foriaddto provide different (usually in-place) behavior thanadd`.

@chepner This mechanism works beautifully in 99% of the cases, but does have some nasty edge cases too. For example, t = (["a"],); t[0] += "b" raises an exception (because the tuple is immutable), but still modifies the list inside of it! That makes sense when you know how the sausage is made, but is otherwise quite surprising and feels like a bug.

@chepner good to know about iadd

@user4815162342 can you elaborate more on this example? Why can I extend list, but I cannot use +=  on label returned by tuple?

The problem is the attempt to assign the (modified in-place) value of t[0].__iadd__("b") back to t[0], which is not allowed. t[0] is mutable, but t itself is not.

@Zimzozaur += is designed to cover the needs of both mutable and immutable objects. You want to be able to write i += 1 where i is an int, and you expect that to work like i = i + 1, i.e. assign a different object to i. But with a list, you want l += [1, 2, 3] to append to the existing list, so as to avoid quadratic behavior when you do that in a loop. To support that with maximum flexibility, __iadd__ can either do the operation in-place and return self, or create a new object and return it (or even decide at run-time between the two).

That leads to the counter-intuitive behavior that when evaluating <place> += <x>, even when the object in <place> supports __iadd__ (like the list does in my example), Python is still obliged to assign the result of __iadd__ back to <place>. In case of tuple, that fails, but __iadd__ has already extended the list.

@user4815162342 can you answer this question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78398978/why-does-python-disallow-the-use-of-the-operator-with-tuples-containing-mutab
It boggled my mind, and I still don't understand it. You may show my with a snippet how the process works.

In my understanding += modifies the list in place and preserves the reference to the same object. + in the other hand creates a new list object and assigns it to the variable. It breaks the reference to the original object.
