Why does Python disallow the use of the += operator with tuples containing mutable objects?
I'm trying to understand why Python restricts the use of the += operator with tuples containing mutable objects.
t = (['a'],)
t[0] += 'b'
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

But even though an error occurs, Python still mutates the list.
t = (['a'],)
try: 
    t[0] += 'b'
except TypeError:
    print(t)  # (['a', 'b'],)

What is the underlying logic behind this behavior?
Shouldn't Python return an object when typing t[0] and then perform mutation?
l = ['a']
t = (l,)
print(t[0] is l)  # True

But instead, there is an interference between tuple and operation performed on a list.
Is any change performed by the operator instead of the method a rebind in this case?

This is covered in the Python programming FAQ: [Why does a_tuple[i] += ‘item’] raise an exception when the addition works?

@wjandrea okay now I see! a += 1 is a = a + 1. But in my case, t[0] += 'b' is result = t[0].__iadd__(['b']); t[0] = result

One slight correction: .__iadd__('b'). Strings are iterable. If you did += 'bc', the resulting list would be ['a', 'b', 'c'].
